# After adding Google Adsense to web site, it gives my CORS errors

Tags: html, google-apps-script, adsense

This is my web site : http://hottravelfares.com/
I added Google Adsense to it. Added all the scripts in  section and also add codes.

Now this is the error i'm getting.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google-analytics.com/collect. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Please visit above web site and open console and you guys will see. I didn't change any code and all added as Google supports says. I know what's CORS issues and tried to fix , but no good. How to fix this ? Please help me.

Comment: have you registered that URL with your google analytics account?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yeah of course. all are done..

Comment: couple possibilities here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839959/google-analytics-tracking-code-giving-cors-error

Comment: Do you fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check CloudFlare settings and rules. I had the same.